# .NET 6 Windows Service Logs Two Duplicate Events At Shutdown

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-6.0

Let me start by stating that this issue does not seem to cause any problems but it certainly doesn't look correct so I thought I would inquire about a *fix*.

I have created a Windows service with .NET 6 loosely following the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service). The biggest difference is that I have stripped out all of the code in the `ExecuteAsync` method so, basically, my service does not actually do anything at the moment.

When I stop the service, I notice that two service stopped events are written to the event log (see image). The two events logged at 9:28:48 PM seem to be duplicates. Can anyone explain why this event is duplicated and how to resolve?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here are the two code files in my project:

**Program.cs**

```
namespace WindowsServiceSandbox
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService(options => {options.ServiceName = "Test Windows Service";})
                .ConfigureServices(services => {services.AddHostedService<Worker>();})
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Worker.cs**

```
namespace WindowsServiceSandbox
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: @gunr2171 - As I mentioned in my original post, I have pretty much stripped out everything from the sample in the referenced article so I am not sure the code I have will be of much use. At any rate, I updated the original post to show what I do have.

Comment: Have you checked the "General" tab for each entry? Is the message logged actually the same. Also check the "Details" tab and than the "XML View", there the "TimeCreated" flag, which shows microsecond resolution. All can help to figure out if that is really the same event logged twice.

Comment: @Christian.K - Please bear in mind that when I used the word duplicate in the original post I was using it in a more general sense. What I mean is that when I have worked with Windows services in the past, only one event was logged when the service started and only one event was logged when the service was stopped. Here, I am seeing two events logged when the service is stopped. This does not seem correct. I checked the things you asked about and the timestamps of the "stopped" events are exactly the same. The only thing that differs is the EventRecordID value and this only differs by 1.